# FactoryGirl association for membership and role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a rails structure of a user that's something like this:

```
User.create(
  email: 'asdf@test.com', 
  password: 'testtest', 
  password_confirmation: 'testtest'
).memberships.create(
  role_id: 1
)
```

Where,

```
Role.create(
  name: 'admin'
)
```

How can I create this association in FactoryGirl?

Models:

**User.rb**

```
has_many :memberships
has_many :roles, through: :memberships
```

**Membership.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :role, dependent: :destroy
```

**Role.rb**

```
has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :memberships
```

Comment: Can you post your Models? especially the belongs_to, has_many and so on.

Comment: Are you counciusly preffering not to use Devise, Rolify and CanCan recipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the associations you use. Here is an example for a has many association

```
factory :user do
  email                 "asdf@test.com"
  password              "testtest" 
  password_confirmation "testtest"
  role
end
```

which creates the user and with the call of 'role' the association will be set

```
factory :role do 
  name "admin"
end
```

regarding your comment, try this:

```
factory :user do
  email                 "asdf@test.com"
  password              "testtest" 
  password_confirmation "testtest"
  role
end

factory :role do 
  name "admin"
end

factory :membership do
  user
  role
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Flo, I just added the models. If a user has_many roles through a membership, would it just be `membership` in the User factory, and then `role` in the Membership factory?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would use child factories to model this while maintaining admin and non-admin factories

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@rmail.com" }
  password "supersecret"
  password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
  factory :admin do
    admin_membership
  end
end
factory :membership do
  user
  role
  factory :admin_membership do
    admin_role
  end
end
factory :role do
  name "role"
  factory :admin_role do
    name "admin"
  end
end
```